# Critical Nonplanar Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, planar-graphs

In Alan Tucker's Applied Combinatorics, it is stated that "A graph G is critical nonplanar if G is nonplanar but any subgraph obtained by removing a vertex is planar."

The question is "Show that critical nonplanar graphs must be connected and cannot have a
vertex whose removal disconnects the graph."

I am not sure how to show this, I have an example of a case where a vertex is removed, resulting in a planar graph, but is there something in the definition of a planar graph that it has to be connected?

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting the word "any".  What they mean is that whatever vertex you remove, the resulting graph will be planar, not that there's some vertex you can remove to make the graph planar.

Comment: But is this the case for all nonplanar graphs, no right? So what does this mean for whether or not the graph is connected?

Comment: No it's not the case.  If you remove a vertex from $K_6$, the graph will still be nonplanar.  Phicar's answer explains why the graph as to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

The deal is that if you have more than one component, then either one or more of the components are non-planar. To see this, suppose $G=G_1\cup G_2,$ such that the is no edge connecting any vertex of $G_1$ to $G_2$ and suppose further that $G_1$ is non-planar, then take any vertex of $G_2$ and is going still to be non-planar. What happens now if there is such vertex that disconnects the graph? It does not belong to a cycle(**why?**), so when you disconnect it, one of the parts is going to be non-planar. Can you show this?

Comment: It would not belong because a cycle is a trail that starts and ends at the same vertex, and this would prevent that from happening, but does planarity require it to be connected? I'm sorry I get pretty confused with all the terms, bipartite, connected, etc.

Comment: @JocelineNatali Yes, you are right, it wouldnt belong to a cycle. No, planarity does not require being connected. Take for example $K_4$ and isolated vertex. The connectivity is require because you need to take **any** vertex out as I explain in the answer.

Comment: So, is it just then by disconnecting you get the possibility of a nonplanar component?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can be connected and taking one vertex being connected(for example $K_5$). But i showed you that if you have a disconnected graph you can get a nonplanar part.